# Dynamic data passing and presenting views of Grid Images in SwiftUIExtensions

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11.3

I am using [SwiftUIExtensions](https://github.com/SwiftExtensions/SwiftUIExtensions) library and wanted to make the image in the “StaggeredGridView” clickable presenting a new view with the clicked image and some related information with it.

Presently I am working as below code, but still not sure how to pass data (index - that is basically image name here).

```
var body: some View {
    Grid(1...20, id: \.self) { index in
        Image("\(index)")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                // Action on Double tapped

                self.showingDetails.toggle()
        }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingDetails) {
                    ProductDetails()
                }

    }
```

My Product view is as below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ProductDetails: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail")
    }
}
```

Xcode version: Xcode 11.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to pass `index` into `ProductDetails` you could do this into the following way:

```
@State var currentIndex = 0
var body: some View {
    Grid(1...20, id: \.self) { index in
        Image("\(index)")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
                // Action on Double tapped
                self.currentIndex = index
                self.showingDetails.toggle()
        }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingDetails) {
                    ProductDetails(selection: self.$currentIndex)
                }

    }


struct ProductDetails: View {
    @Binding var selection: Int
    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail \(selection)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one is better to use to share data Sheet or Navigation? Any example with NavigationView?

Comment: Depending on the needs of you application... both are applicable. SO has many examples of using NavigationView to show details, just search.